# Is it possible to map REST actions like RoRails style when using Struts2?

Tags: java, rest, struts2, struts

In rails i can do like this " get '/events/:id_event', to:'events#show', as: 'show_event' "

Using rest-plugin for Struts2 the REST methods are choosen based on convention. 
An example:

if i need to go a page where i have a list i will use GET: /produts    and by convention the plugin knows that the action to be mapped will be "index".

If i need to show information from some product the convention plugin expects GET /product/123 to map for "show" method

If i need to create a new produt the convention plugin expects POST /product to map for "create" method

My problem is:

I have a search form with only textfield input parameter;

I need to know how am i supposed to set my form to invoke "show" rest method "/product/id"

```html
<s:form action="/product" method="get" >
  <s:textfield name="id"/> 
<s:form/>
```

after i submit the url is "..../product?id=3" instead of ".../product/3", so the convention see "..../product?id=3" and ignore "?id=3" and send to "index" rest method instead of "show"

Comment: Because it's a form and you're using a get request. If you want to create a RESTful *link* then do so as a link. Searching is a different operation than resourceful lookup.

Comment: If you working with REST you should use SEO friendly URLs.

Comment: Thank you both  for the quick reply.

@RomanC i search for SEO friendly urls and i found some interesting things [link](http://www.errorhell.com/2012/01/seo-friendly-urls-with-struts-2-search-example/) that explain how to transform the form params product?id=3 in product/3, but only using as example the normal actions without the Rest plugin..

Can you please help me figure out how to do it ?

Best regards,

Jorge Maia

Comment: @JorginhoMaia So, what prevents you to follow the example? However I don't think you can do it with Rest, unless you show how to change the http method.

Comment: @RomanC i tried to adapt the style used by the tutorial, but since this follows only the Action methodology is a little bit difficult to replicate the same procedure.  Instead of one Action.java for each request , when using the REST plugin a Controller.java is implemented that respond to more than one request..   I'm a little bit lost here..   I need to know more about wildcards mapping to understand how mapping is override using REST.